# "The System failed to establish a connection"

Tags: vb.net

I have a concern with my connection which I cannot establish a connection even though my database connection was open. I put all of the correct strings to establish but none was connected. This code is supposed to log on the user for an specific system.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module SQLConn
Public ServerMySQL As String
Public PortMySQL As String
Public UserNameMySQL As String
Public PwdMySQL As String
Public DBNameMySQL As String
Public sqL As String
Public ds As New DataSet()
Public cmd As MySqlCommand
Public dr As MySqlDataReader
Public da As New MySqlDataAdapter

Public conn As New MySqlConnection

Sub getData()
    Dim AppName As String = Application.ProductName

    Try
        DBNameMySQL = GetSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_Name", "temp")
        ServerMySQL = GetSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_IP", "temp")
        PortMySQL = GetSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_Port", "temp")
        UserNameMySQL = GetSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_User", "temp")
        PwdMySQL = GetSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_Password", "temp")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("System registry was not established, you can set/save " & _
        "these settings by pressing F1", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub ConnDB()
    conn.Close()
    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server = '" & ServerMySQL & "';  " _
                                     & "Port = '" & PortMySQL & "'; " _
                                     & "Database = '" & DBNameMySQL & "'; " _
                                     & "user id = '" & UserNameMySQL & "'; " _
                                     & "password = '" & PwdMySQL & "'"

        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("The system failed to establish a connection", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Database Settings")
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub DisconnMy()

    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()

End Sub

Sub SaveData()
    Dim AppName As String = Application.ProductName

    SaveSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_Name", DBNameMySQL)
    SaveSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_IP", ServerMySQL)
    SaveSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_Port", PortMySQL)
    SaveSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_User", UserNameMySQL)
    SaveSetting(AppName, "DBSection", "DB_Password", PwdMySQL)

    MsgBox("Database connection settings are saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub



 End Module
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Remove the quotes around the values extracted to build your connectionstring. You are not working with database strings

Comment: What are the actual exception details (not your message)? You say your database connection was opened but I don't believe it. Check if your MySql provider has a ConnectionStringBuilder class to prevent connection string syntax errors.

Comment: You should be using a `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to build your connection string and then you would avoid such mistakes. Of course, any example of creating a MySQL connection string would show that you don't use single quotes. Try taking a look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Comment: perhaps google ain't working for you. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html